# Bezier curve based objective function

Tags: polynomials, optimization, convex-analysis, bezier-curve, non-convex-optimization

Could you please help me by explaining the second page of the paper in the link below? Particularly, why the objective function is presented as a sum of the integral of the norm of the derivatives? Also, how can the non-convex constraints be included mathematically in the optimization problem

paper's link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.10219.pdf